# Create lagged variables in panel data in Julia

Tags: julia, lag

I am trying to generate lagged variables using panel data (ID and year). By each ID, it might have different years of panel and sometimes years are not continuous within ID group. For example, we have the data set below:

| ID | Year | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | 3 |
| 1 | 2002 | 1 |
| 1 | 2006 | 2 |
| 1 | 2007 | 2 |
| 2 | 2002 | 1 |
| 2 | 2003 | 5 |
| 3 | 2006 | 2 |
| 3 | 2007 | 2 |
| 3 | 2008 | 4 |

And the lagged variable for x that I want to generate is:

| ID | Year | x | x_lag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | 3 | . |
| 1 | 2002 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2006 | 2 | . |
| 1 | 2007 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2002 | 1 | . |
| 2 | 2003 | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 2006 | 2 | . |
| 3 | 2007 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2008 | 4 | 2 |

I found some other answers to how to create lagged variables by groups but it does not work for me because some of IDs in my data set have discontinuous years (ex. row 2-3 in the example above).

So, I am using the function that I have written down below:

```
function lagged(data,x)
    for c in x
        data[:,c*"_lag"] .= 0.0
    end
    allowmissing!(data)
    for row in eachrow(data)
        for c in x
            if filter(y -> y.id == row.id && y.year == row.year - 1, data)[:,c] == []
                row[c*"_lag"] = missing
            else
                row[c*"_lag"] = filter(y -> y.id == row.id && y.year == row.year - 1, data)[:,c][1]
            end
        end
    end
    return data
end
```

But it is extremely slow... Is there any faster way to create lagged variables in panel data with discontinuous years? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
julia> df = DataFrame(ID=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                      Year=[2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008],
                      x=[3,1,2,2,1,5,2,2,4])
9×3 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     Year   x
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1   2001      3
   2 │     1   2002      1
   3 │     1   2006      2
   4 │     1   2007      2
   5 │     2   2002      1
   6 │     2   2003      5
   7 │     3   2006      2
   8 │     3   2007      2
   9 │     3   2008      4

julia> function lag_v(year, x)
           result = missings(eltype(x), length(x))
           length(x) < 2 && return result
           last = first(year)
           for i in 2:length(x)
               current = year[i]
               current-last == 1 && (result[i] = x[i-1])
               last = current
           end
           return result
       end
lag_v (generic function with 1 method)

julia> transform(groupby(df, :ID), [:Year, :x] => lag_v => :x_lag)
9×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     Year   x      x_lag
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64?
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │     1   2001      3  missing
   2 │     1   2002      1        3
   3 │     1   2006      2  missing
   4 │     1   2007      2        2
   5 │     2   2002      1  missing
   6 │     2   2003      5        1
   7 │     3   2006      2  missing
   8 │     3   2007      2        2
   9 │     3   2008      4        2
```

and is it fast enough?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do

```
transform!(groupby(df, :id), :x => lag, :year => lag)
```

And then only keep the `x_lag` values where `year_lag` is 1?

EDIT

Now that I'm not on my phone here's what I meant in DataFrames minilanguage:

```
julia> using DataFrames; import ShiftedArrays: lag

julia> df = DataFrame(ID=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
                             Year=[2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008],
                             x=[3,1,2,2,1,5,2,2,4]);

julia> transform!(groupby(df, :ID),
               [:Year, :x] => ((y, x) -> ifelse.(coalesce.(y .- lag(y) .== 1, false), lag(x), missing))  => :x_lag)
9×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     Year   x      x_lag
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64?
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │     1   2001      3  missing
   2 │     1   2002      1        3
   3 │     1   2006      2  missing
   4 │     1   2007      2        2
   5 │     2   2002      1  missing
   6 │     2   2003      5        1
   7 │     3   2006      2  missing
   8 │     3   2007      2        2
   9 │     3   2008      4        2
```

I haven't benchmarked all the solutions in this thread, but testing this on a 10-million row DataFrame this runs in about 1 second on my laptop, which seems acceptable?

```
julia> df_test = DataFrame(id = repeat(1:1_000_000, inner = 10), year = reduce(vcat, [sort(rand(2000:2015, 10)) for _ ∈ 1:1_000_000]), x = rand(10_000_000));

julia> @time transform!(groupby(df_test, :id),
               [:year, :x] => ((y, x) -> ifelse.(coalesce.(y .- lag(y) .== 1, false), lag(x), missing))  => :x_lag);
  1.139166 seconds (9.33 M allocations: 940.402 MiB, 7.77% gc time, 16.18% compilation time)
```

Comment: not `year_lag` but difference of `Year` and `year_lag` equal to 1. Howver, if OP is sensitive to performance it is faster to use a custom function I think (it will allocate less).

Comment: Thanks Bogumil - don't post on your phone from the pub is the lesson here! Have corrected in the above and added a simple benchmark, I think the minilanguage is doing very well here!

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `ShiftedArrays`

##### Data

```
julia> using ShiftedArrays
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(ID = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
               Year = [2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008], 
               x = [3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4])
```

Add helper column *is* to check if lagged *Year* == *Year*, then
remove missings, create and fill *x_lag* column and finally remove the helper column.

```
julia> function do_lag!(frame)
         for grp in groupby(frame, :ID)
           grp.is = (ShiftedArrays.lag(grp.Year, 1) .+ 1) .== grp.Year
         end

         frame.is[ismissing.(frame.is)] .= false
         frame.x_lag = Vector{Union{Int, String}}(repeat(["."], size(frame)[1]))
         frame.x_lag[findall(frame.is)] = 
           ShiftedArrays.lag(frame.x)[findall(frame.is)]
         select!(frame, Not([:is]))
       end
```

```
julia> do_lag!(df)
9×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     Year   x      x_lag
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Union…
─────┼─────────────────────────────
   1 │     1   2001      3  .
   2 │     1   2002      1  3
   3 │     1   2006      2  .
   4 │     1   2007      2  2
   5 │     2   2002      1  .
   6 │     2   2003      5  1
   7 │     3   2006      2  .
   8 │     3   2007      2  2
   9 │     3   2008      4  2
```

Answer (score 0):

And another option, without defining a function, but using a `leftjoin` with next-year version of `df`:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(ID=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3],
  Year=[2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2008],
  x=[3,1,2,2,1,5,2,2,4]);
```

```
julia> leftjoin(df, select(df, :ID, 
  :Year => ByRow(Base.Fix2(+,1)) => :Year, 
  :x => :lag_x); on=[:ID, :Year])
9×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     Year   x      lag_x   
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64?  
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │     1   2002      1        3
   2 │     1   2007      2        2
   3 │     2   2003      5        1
   4 │     3   2007      2        2
   5 │     3   2008      4        2
   6 │     1   2001      3  missing 
   7 │     1   2006      2  missing 
   8 │     2   2002      1  missing 
   9 │     3   2006      2  missing
```

It's easier to see what this join does after sorting (though not necessary):

```
julia> sort!(leftjoin(df, 
  select(df, :ID, :Year => ByRow(Base.Fix2(+,1)) => :Year, 
  :x => :lag_x); on=[:ID, :Year]), [:ID, :Year])
9×4 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     Year   x      lag_x   
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64?  
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │     1   2001      3  missing 
   2 │     1   2002      1        3
   3 │     1   2006      2  missing 
   4 │     1   2007      2        2
   5 │     2   2002      1  missing 
   6 │     2   2003      5        1
   7 │     3   2006      2  missing 
   8 │     3   2007      2        2
   9 │     3   2008      4        2
```

This solution has the benefit of being easier to use when eventually the underlying DataFrame storage becomes a database (like SQLite, or Postgres), once the OP's operation scales to 100M users :-)